# Remove all images created by Imageview

Tags: android

I am creating n number of images with wordImage and assign a differnt Id.This happens on a button click add. There is another button remove when I click that all the images that I have created should be removed from the view(Head is the view). Plz help how to do that.

```
 onclick of add button
             for (int getwordcount = 0; getwordcount <5; getwordcount++) {
                                int i=0;
                                WordImage = new ImageView(this);
                                WordImage.setId(getwordcount);
                                WordImage.setBackgroundResource(alphabetsimages[getwordcount]);
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                                para.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                                para.leftMargin=maragin+=54;
                                para.bottomMargin=25;
                                para.width=BtnNext.getWidth()/3;
                                para.height=BtnNext.getHeight();
                                WordImage.setLayoutParams(para);
                                WordImage.setTag(getSplitString);
                                Head.addView(WordImage);
                                }
```

`onclick` of remove button
        only the last ------------->   **`Head.removeView(WordImage);`**
        create image  is removed from view. 
        How do I remove all images created using wordimage.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `creating n number of images with wordImage` What kind of 'images' are you creating? `a button click add.` Where are you adding to ? To Head i see. What is Head? Please show full remove code. What is 'WordImage'?

Answer (score 0):

**WordImage** saves link just for the last **ImageView**. Previous link lost in this line:

```
WordImage = new ImageView(this);
```

This is why **Head.removeView(WordImage)** removes only the last image.
If you want delete all added image elements, the easiest way do this is to add RelativeLayout container like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"        >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Head" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add"
            android:onClick="onClickAdd"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="remove"
            android:onClick="onClickRemove"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can delete all images only by one command:

```
Head.removeAllViews();
```

In other case, if you need to remove separate images, you have to delete your items in cycle similar to your "add" block:

```
for (int getwordcount = 0; getwordcount <alphabetsimages.length; getwordcount++) {
            Head.removeView(findViewById(getwordcount));
}
```

Activity class will be like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout Head;
    int alphabetsimages[] = {android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float, android.R.drawable.btn_dropdown, android.R.drawable.btn_minus, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map};
    ImageView WordImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }
    public void onClickAdd(View v){
        int margin = 0;
        for (int getwordcount = 0; getwordcount <alphabetsimages.length; getwordcount++) {
            int i=0;
            WordImage = new ImageView(this);
            WordImage.setId(getwordcount);
            WordImage.setBackgroundResource(alphabetsimages[getwordcount]);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            para.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            para.leftMargin=margin+=54;
            para.bottomMargin=25;
            para.width = 40;
            para.height = 40;
            WordImage.setLayoutParams(para);
            Head= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Head);
            Head.addView(WordImage);
        }
    }

    public void onClickRemove(View v){
        //Head.removeAllViews();
        for (int getwordcount = 0; getwordcount <alphabetsimages.length; getwordcount++) {
            Head.removeView(findViewById(getwordcount));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's what you need!